# HTML Drag and Drop, dragover event returns the child element and not the parent

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, drag-and-drop

In the provided example, when I drag any element over the "Category1" the console.log outputs the child element "DIV" instead of the parent element "LI".

Any solutions would be appreciated.

```js
document.addEventListener('dragover', function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(event.target.tagName);
    }, true);
```

```html
<ul>
        <li draggable='true'><div draggable="false">Category 1</div> 
        <ul>
            <li draggable='true'> * Item 1 </li>
            <li draggable='true'> *  Item 2 </li>
            <li draggable='true'> *  item 3 </li>
        </ul>
        <li draggable='true'><div draggable="false">Category 2</div> 
        <ul>
            <li draggable='true'> * Item 1 </li>
            <li draggable='true'> *  Item 2</li>
        </ul>
        </li>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

use "drag" instead of "dragover" in EventListener.

```
document.addEventListener('drag', function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(event.target.tagName);
},true);
```

Comment: Thank you but your solution gets the event of the moving element and not the event of the element which I drag over.

Answer (score 0):

Was thinking of using a FOR loop to get through the DOM until I find the LI.

```
function getfirstLI(el)
{
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
if (el.tagName == "LI") return el;
if (el.tagName == "UL") return null;
if (el.tagName == "body") return null;
el = el.parentNode;
}
```